# Grabbing HTML from rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What i would like to do is to allow the user to draw a rectangle on top of a website, and grabbing all the html he sees in that rectangle.

I know this can't be done perfectly but I was wondering how well it could be done.

i was thinking of doing something like this

```
function getTagsInArea(p1, p2){
    var ret = {}
    for(x=p1.x;x<p2.x;x+=10){
        for(y=p1.y;y<p2.y;y+=10){
            var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
            if(typeof ret[el] =='undefined'){
                ret[el]=el;
            }
            else{console.log('not appending '+el);}
        } 
    } 
    return ret;
}
```

This gives me more or less the tags in that area. I wonder if there is a generic way to build trees from these tags and output html.

I am looking for something like a DocumentFragment. Such as selectionContents  from this snippet:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
```

Is there an obvious way to do this? 
One of the problems so far is that some of the tags i get using the above func are 'body' and 'div id="page"' stuff, which contain what i am looking for. Any solution would need to figure out how to take only those parts of the surrounding tags taht are needed.

For instance, if i have a long paragraph and recntagled half of it, i want only the text in my selection to be returned.

Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: This is what i have so far (thanks Sour Lemon). http://jsfiddle.net/cgKzv/6/ . its closer to what i want to end up with (which is a tree structure). think i'll be fine from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript and jQuery aren't my strong points but I thought I would try to write a small example of what I think you want.

Unfortunately I don't have time to finish so currently the selection box can only drag left and down but if it is what you'e after then I'm sure you will be able to alter it.

Currently I'm just building a text list of selected tags which I'm printing out after mouse up, but it loops through in order so it shouldn't be much problem to store all of these tags in an array if you wanted.

Of course you could also use $(this).html() in the each loop to get the contents of each selected tag too.

Sorry if I mis-understood your question, but was this the kind of thing you were after?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgKzv/ (Written and tested in Chrome)

Comment: what you wrote works pretty well. though i think iterating all nodes might be much. i liked that it doesnt pick up invisible stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/cgKzv/1/ . stuff that is hidden it does pick up :http://jsfiddle.net/cgKzv/5/ . Here you can see that when you select the gray div what it hides is also picked up. i think that if i try to use it, the hidden stuff getting picked up might be a problem. though i am not sure yet. thanks a lot for your answer. you've helped a lot.

Comment: @s.shpiz Currently it will select everything whether it is hidden or not. So I just made a small change to the jquery selector in the get_elements function - now it will select everything within the #main div that does not have a class of .unselectable; so if you don't want certain things to be selected just give it a class of unselectable and it will ignore it. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cgKzv/8/

Answer (score 1):

Provided you know the area of your triangle, you can possibly surround all characters of text with span tags like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nkgj/2/) and THEN do a check if those span tags fall within your rectangle.  To make it easier, I would assign classes to these span tags.  Then, concatenate the text using $.each() to loop the span tags,check if they fall within the rectangle, and , if they do, concatenate to a string variable.  Also, if you use  document.elementFromPoint(), it will only return the element that is at that position with the *highest* z-index (in case your had some elements layered).

Comment: not sure i understand your suggestion. Do oyu mean going over all the tags returned by the above function, and adding span tags to their innards. And then checking the spans' x,y coordinates to check if they are in my area? i think that might work, but i am not sure that is what you meant. is it ? :)

Comment: @s.shpiz - I guess my question to you would be whether you want to extract markup or the actual text in the markup.  If you just want the elements within the rectangle, you should first arrange a container for your elements in which the select HTML elements will reside in.  If you truly meant to extract text, then use the link I provided to wrap each character in a span tag.  This would then allow you to select all characters that fall within your rectangle.  you can use $('span').each() to concatenate the inner text in order to reconstitute the original strings.

Comment: "And then checking the spans' x,y coordinates to check if they are in my area? i think that might work"  This will  if you just want the text.  The purpose of the span wraps are to make each character of the text to stand alone as an element.   Then, as you would just need to check to see if any of the elements reside within your rectangle.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I would like to get a raw html tree (or trees if the html inside is 2 separate divs or something) from the area. sort of a printscreen.

Comment: I think Sour Lemon's solution can help.  After you select with the rectangle, what would theoretically happen next?  If you gave me some idea, I might understand how to help.  Thanks.